# Noise cancellation using RLS filter

Tags: adaptive-filters, adaptive-algorithms, noise-cancellation

I am trying to create an adaptive noise canceller using the RLS algorithm. The dsp toolbox from matlab offers [the RLS adaptive filter](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.rlsfilter-class.html) already implemented, so this saved me some trouble.

My goal is to filter out the hearth beat signal from the muscle signal, however, so far I have had zero to no success. After reading a decent amount of articles on the internet, I found out that the adaptive filters are suitable for this purpose as I have a reference signal of the electrocardiogram, which I want to remove. I chose the RLS algorithm, as it converges faster than the LMS algorithm, so it should be the better option. The filter order is set to 60 and the `ForgettingFactor` is 0.999, which according to multiple sources, should result the removal of the noise signal, however, in my case the hearth beat signal is still significantly noticeable.

[image: Raw Data]
[image: Filtered Data]

From the attached images, you can see that the signal is not filtered. Should I process the signal before using the adaptive filter or is the method wrong (or badly implemented) and I should try something else?

Comment: I don't know whether it'll be useful for anyone but let me restate that the adaptive filters are not just the type of *filter & go* systems. They require a great deal of fine tuning for succesful applications to any serious real world problem... And fine tuning requires a great deal of *dsp engineering expertise*...

Comment: Can you explain what fine tuning means? I am relatively new to signal processing, so I have little to no knowledge in this area. It may have been naive from my side to think that I can simply use what is given from matlab and just tweak the `order` and `ForgettingFactor` parameters until I receive the wanted result.

Comment: Fine tuning is an engineering terminology, not specific to dsp. Those two are very fundamental parameters. You can perform a parameter trace to see which combination gives the best result... Expertise relates to problem definition and proposed solution architectures. Anyway, this is a nice problem. In the mean time can you please **upload** those two signals in Matlab readable form? Lets see the answers...

Comment: Well, I have over ten channels, so I am not sure, if I would be able to upload them all. What I find odd, is that the filter works for some of the channels and for others not. Furthermore, if I use a different reference signal, it works almost perfect for all channels. (e.g. if I use a `moving weighted window` with ``window size = 7` on my signal to get a reference signal).

Comment: ok interesting. Lets see the responses.